# millisecond time in ahk

Tags: time, autohotkey

I'm looking for a way to save timestamps to the millisecond in ahk.

```
FormatTime, stamp, , HH:mm:ss
        FileAppend,
        (
            %stamp%,`n 
        ), C:\%thefilename%.txt
```

The above code only provides time to the second.  My events sometimes take place twice a second.  Can ahk provide this level of detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FileAppend,
(
   %A_Hour%:%A_Min%:%A_Sec% (%A_MSec%),`n
), C:\%thefilename%.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at using the internal %A_TickCount% (approx. ms accuracy) variable to create an Elapsed Time value between two timing points?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
startTime := %A_TickCount%

;Do your things

elapsedTime := startTime - %A_TickCount%
```

Should do the trick to get ms time.